# moment object gives different date when formatted

Tags: momentjs, utc

formatting a moment object gives me a different result to the one I expect to see

I tried removing UTC but still don't get the result i expect

```
moment.utc().startOf("day").subtract(schedule.pastDays, "days")
```

returns date object with:
_d: Wed Jul 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Etc Greenwich Standard Time) {}

but formatting it:
moment.utc().startOf("day").subtract(schedule.pastDays, "days").format()

returns:
"2019-07-16T22:00:00Z"

Where did the 2hrs go that kicked the date back to the previous day?

I expected to see:
"2019-07-17T00:00:00Z" as the date object would suggest.

Comment: To simplify my question, any chance anyone can explain it to me please?
moment("7/18/2019", "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
returns "07/17/2019"
why?????!!!
and how to have moment return "7/18/2019" as I would expect?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if I do not specify a timezone, moment presumes utc and so adjusts when I format(). This however works and keeps the formatted time local:

```
var tzDay = moment().utcOffset(moment().utcOffset(), true).local()
var newDay = tzDay.format('MMDDYYYY');
console.log(newDay)

//returns today's date without any utc adjustment
```